# What is CLI-Loop ? What's the difference with normal loop?

Tags: python, loops, command-line-interface

I was doing some research about Python.

And I saw something like this.

```
# Start CLI-Loop
while True:
    try:
        text = raw_input()
    except:
        text = error()

    if text == condition_1:
        do_Some_Other_Things_1()
        break

    elif text == condition_2:
        do_Some_Other_Things_2()
```

Is CLI-Loop stands for "Command Line Interface Loop" ?

If not, what does it mean?

What's so special about it?

Comment: There's nothing special about it. It is just a loop that takes user input. Also see [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about the loop; the author simply introduces the code block, stating that it'll interpret commands.

Which is exactly what the loop does; using `raw_input()`, it asks for user input from the terminal, then executes functions based on the input. In other words, it takes commands, interfacing with the user.

Answer (score 0):

CLI indeed stands for Command Line Interface. There's nothing special about this loop, it's just called "the CLI loop" to indicate it's a loop handling the input taken from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but I think I had to chose @MartijnPieters because his answer and comment are more detailed.